# Compare two images color values parallel with canvas

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, rgb

I am trying to create a JS-Application which allows to compare image values from two images at the same position.

My idea is to upload the images and store them as variables in an object. If I move my mouse a canvas element in the browser, the coordinates should be taken from this and be used to request the image-values from the stored canvases.

```js
const images = new ImageHandler(); // ToDo: UpperCaseLetters as constant

(function createFileUploadButton() {
    var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
    x.setAttribute("type", "file");
    x.id = "imageUploader";
    document.body.appendChild(x);
})();


function ImageHandler() {
    const  WIDTH = 1030;
    const  HEIGHT = 650;

    let upperImage = null;
    let lowerImage = null;


    this.setImage = imageData => {
        if (upperImage && lowerImage) {
            alert("Seite neu laden, um neue Bilder zu laden");
        }
        console.log("lowerImage: " + lowerImage)
        if (!lowerImage) {
            let canvas = this.getNewCanvasWithImage(imageData);
            console.log("setting lower image")
            lowerImage = canvas;
        } else {
            console.log("ELSE");
            let canvas = this.getNewCanvasWithImage(imageData);
            console.log("setting upper image")
            upperImage = canvas;
        }
    };




    this.getNewCanvasWithImage = imageData => {
        console.log("getNewCanvas")
        console.log("typeof imageData " + typeof imageData);

        let canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        //canvas.id = "";
        //canvas.style.zIndex = 2; ? Wofür gut? Brauchen wir das?
        canvas.width = WIDTH;
        canvas.height = HEIGHT;

        let context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        let image = new Image();
        image.src = imageData;
        context.drawImage(image, 1, 1);

        return canvas;
    };



    this.getColorValues = (coordinates) => {
        console.log("X " + coordinates.x);
        console.log("Y " + coordinates.y);
        var lowerImageContext = lowerImage.getContext('2d');
        var lowerImageData = lowerImageContext.getImageData(coordinates.x, coordinates.y, 1, 1).data;
        console.log("lowerImageData: " + lowerImageData);

        var upperImageContext = upperImage.getContext('2d');
        var upperImageData = upperImageContext.getImageData(coordinates.x, coordinates.y, 1, 1).data;
        console.log("upperImageData: " + upperImageData);
        
    };

    this.drawUpper = () => {
        console.log("appendUpper to body");
    };

    this.drawLower = () => {
        document.appendChild(this.lowerImage);
    };



}


document.getElementById("imageUploader").onchange = function(event) {

    var input = event.target;
    var reader = new FileReader();

    // Callback when the file is loaded
    reader.onload = function() {
        try {
            var filecontent = reader.result; // Loaded content
            images.setImage(filecontent);

        } catch (error) {
            alert(error);
        }

    };

    // Read the file
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
};






$('#canvas').mousemove(function(e) {
    console.log("mousemove");
    var pos = findPos(this);
    var xPos = e.pageX - pos.x;
    var yPos = e.pageY - pos.y;
    //var coordinates = "x=" + x + ", y=" + y;
    console.log("x=" + xPos + ", y=" + yPos);
    var coordinates = {};
    coordinates.x = xPos;
    coordinates.y = yPos;

    images.getColorValues(coordinates);
});



function findPos(obj) {
    var curleft = 0, curtop = 0;
    if (obj.offsetParent) {
        do {
            curleft += obj.offsetLeft;
            curtop += obj.offsetTop;
        } while (obj = obj.offsetParent);
        return {x: curleft, y: curtop};
    }
    return undefined;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="250" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</html>
```

Unfortunately I can not find my error.
I get for the image values only zeros. 
One aspect could be that the images need time to load but even if i wait several moments it does not work properly. Sometimes I get the values from one image but never from both.

Can anyone spot the error or has an idea how one could compare the color values from two images more easily?

Kind regards
Niklas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `onload` event of `Image` can help you make sure that the image is loaded and ready for use.

```
    let image = new Image();
    image.onload = function(){
        context.drawImage(this, 1, 1);
    }
    image.src = imageData;
```

That being said, I am not sure if there are other issues in your code.

> If you try to call drawImage() before the image has finished loading,
>   it won't do anything (or, in older browsers, may even throw an
>   exception). So you need to be sure to use the load event so you don't
>   try this before the image has loaded:

You can check [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Using_images) for a comprehensive documentation